# How do I make a scorecard type layout CardView?

Tags: android, material-design

I have been battling with GridLayout and TableLayout for the past couple of hours and for the life of me can't figure out a way to make a CardView that looks like the following:
[image: desired score card layout]

Currently I have a CardView parent with this GridLayout is its child:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <!--FirstRow-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/away_logo"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/scores_layout"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="0.5"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0.4"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/away_score_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_score_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:text="11"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.33"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>
    <!--SecondRow-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/away_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.33"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="Team"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.33"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="Team"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <!--LastRow-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_rink_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:text="7:00P.M.atBotany"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Which gives this layout where the stars are placeholders to visualise where the ImageViews are and the scores are 1 - 13:

[image: logos and scores have bunched and left aligned and everything has been pushed towards the top]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:text="7:00 P.M. at Venue"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                tools:src="@drawable/team_1_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                tools:text="Team 1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="1 - 3"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                tools:src="@drawable/team_2_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="8dp"
                tools:text="Team 2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using relative layout to contain the inner content (also can do it for the title too), and align the views according to the parents, left, right, and center portions and it should work for you.